# Why would piezo voltage output at high temperature increase with use?

Tags: material-science, piezoelectric

I am using an inexpensive piezoelectric diaphragm as a contact sensor but am getting an unexpected effect: When theelement is stressed by cyclicly putting under pressure and releasing the pressure at a high temperature the voltage output increases with more cycles. What is causing the increase?

More details: the piezo is a Murata 7BB-27-4LO, pressure is applied evenly across the surface (no bending) and pressure is 4.5N reduced to 0.5N every 5 seconds, monitoring is by an oscilloscope with an X10 10megohm probe. At 50 degrees C the voltage output increased from 12V to 13.5V over 50,000 cycles - which may be due to instrument or procedural error, but the problem comes at 80 degrees C where the voltage increased from 3.8V to 5.8V over 10,000 cycles. For comparison, at 20 degrees the output dropped from 25V to 23V over 100,000 cycles.

This is being used as a sensor for RepRap 3D printers, see forums.reprap.org/read.php?1,635075,page=1

A quick edit to show the increase over 1 day or 16,000 cycles.

[image: Increase in voltage over 1 day or 16,000 cycles at 80 degrees C]

[image: Jig for cycling the pressure at temperature]

Resting load is set by lifting at the return spring adjusting eye with a spring dynamometer, relaxed pressure by lifting the free end of the parallel mechanism and actuator rod over-travel by is adjusted to 0.3mm. This is done after each test but no adjustment has been needed